# addressused on email "from" attribute

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm using a pre-operation plugin on create of email to change the entity reference on the email's **"from"** attribute.
This is the code I use for the setting:

```
((EntityCollection)entity.Attributes["from"]).Entities[0].Attributes["partyid"] = erQueue;  //erQueue is an entityReference of a certain queue
```

I also want the email to be sent from the **queue** email adddress, and not from the original sender's address.
should I also set the **"addressused** attribue of the "from" activityparty, or would it happen automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I checked, the email was sent with the email address of the original system user in the "from" field. So I had to change the addressused of the activityparty in the from attribute:

```
((EntityCollection)entity.Attributes["from"]).Entities[0].Attributes["addressused"] = sQueueEmailAddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

CRM should default the email address used to primary email address of the selected record.

I've only used `addressused` in the past when I wanted to use an email address other than the primary email address of the selected record.

So in your case I don't think you need to set the `addressused`.

Slightly old documentation but still true and relevant I believe.

[activityparty.addressused Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ve/library/cc151451.aspx)

> The property activityparty.partyid contains the ID of an account,
> contact, lead or systemuser. For account, contact or lead, the
> property emailaddress1 is used as the default value for the e-mail
> address. If this value is blank, emailaddress2 is used, and so on. For
> systemuser, the default e-mail address is internalemailaddress.
>
> To override this default, you can specify an alternate address as the value for addressused. For example, if you set addressused to the
> value "someone@example.com", that e-mail address will be used.

Comment: Thanks. When I check the value in ((EntityCollection)entity.Attributes["from"]).Entities[0].Attributes["addressused"]  it's the value of the original systemuser, and not of the queue I set it to be. The question is if it has a meaning. Also, in the quote you gave, there is no mentioning of queues...

Comment: @cookya, if you haven't already it might be worth checking outside of the plugin. There is a reasonable chance that CRM might not change the `addressused` until the save occurs. Assuming queue has same behaviour as described in quote.